# How to initialize Generic Type Double Pointer in Heap Memory C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

This is how we initialize a single pointer inside the heap

```
int *p;
p = new Int(5)
```

I don't have a good understanding of initializing pointers.  Now I want to initialize a double-pointer in `create()` function. How can i do that?

```
struct Node
{

    struct Node *lchild;
    int data;
    struct Node *rchild;

};


struct Queue{
    int size;
    int front ;
    int rear;
    Node **Q;
};

void create(struct Queue *q, int size)
{
    q->size = size;
    q->front = q->rear = -1;
    q->Q = new Node*(Node); // This line is not working


}
```

Comment: Read also the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) to be invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`)...), of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...) and of tools like [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)

Comment: sure but I'm new to C++. Can you please correct the last line of `create()` function where I'm facing an error?

Comment: No, I don't have time for that, and **StackOverflow is not a do-my-homework service**. But look into the messages given by `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) to improve your C++ code. For your next question, provide some [mre] with a `main` function, and show *explicitly* your compilation command. Look also inside the source code of [fish](https://fishshell.com/) - is is open source

Comment: Explain why you are not allowed to read C++ books and use [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

Comment: I'm asking for homework, I wrote this code myself and now getting errors while initializing double-pointer, before posting here I searched on the internet but could not find anything may be due to my keywords. btw thanks for response

Comment: Are you allowed to read documentation and use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) ? Are you allowed to read a C++ standard like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or better? **What C++ programming book did you read?** They have hundreds of pages, and are printed on paper. Did you read the wikipedia for [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming))s? Are you forbidden to read wikipedia? Be aware that C++ is a very difficult language

Comment: Read also (on paper) the [*Introduction to algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) book and wikipedia entries for [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)s and [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Read also [*Teach yourself programming in ten years*](http://www.norvig.com/21-days.html), **so be patient and work hard**. Use the debugger (and don't trust the Internet too much). The major tool for coding and debugging programs is your brain.

Comment: And reading (on paper) [*the GC handbook*](https://gchandbook.org/) is very relevant to your question. It explains in details what is a pointer and how you manage them. You could also read Wilson's [*Uniprocessor Garbage Collection techniques*](https://3e8.org/pub/pdf-t1/gcsurvey.pdf) paper online

Answer (score 2):

Your not working line allocates a Node Pointer on the heap, you need to allocate a node on the heap and in your case an extra pointer to that allocated node and return the pointer to the pointer to the node.

```
void create(struct Queue *q, int size)
{
    q->size = size;
    q->front = q->rear = -1;
    q->Q = new Node*;
    *(q->Q) = new Node;
}
```

Be careful regarding memory leaks here!

**######################################**

**As this is a working, but rather bad implementation, I recommend you to first understand how pointers in C/C++ are working and as you use C++ use container provided by the STL as they are tested very well!**

**######################################**